# how do I run ccm (Cassandra Cluster Manager) command on windows

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, ccm

I have followed the instructions on `Datastax`'s website to install `ccm`. -

https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/ccm-2-0-and-windows

and

https://pypi.org/project/ccm/3.1.4/

The `ccm` was installed successfully but when I try to run it, I get error that `ccm` is not a recognised command.

```
c:\..\ccm-3.1.4.tar\dist\ccm-3.1.4>pip install ccm
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Collecting ccm
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fc/ab/b51afd466cc4acf2192e230ddb6fd3adb56066f05c7be1852af7bd655068/ccm-3.1.4.tar.gz (72kB)
     |################################| 81kB 640kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: pyYaml in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from ccm) (5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.4.1 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from ccm) (1.12.0)
Installing collected packages: ccm
  Running setup.py install for ccm ... done
Successfully installed ccm-3.1.4

C:\...\dist\ccm-3.1.4>ccm create test -v 3.11.3
'ccm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have added the path `C:\Users\manu\Documents\manu\ccm-3.1.4.tar\dist\ccm-3.1.4` in `PATH` variable.

How do I run `ccm` on Windows?

Comment: I am not a big windows user, but what do the file permissions say? I am pretty sure windows has a setting or checkbox that allows a file to be marked Executable

Answer (score 1):

I had to set `PYTHON_HOME -> C:\<python_root>\` in `PATH` variable

Answer (score 0):

You might consider alternative approach to CCM, which doesn't require python dependencies. Like running cassandra in docker containers and managing with docker-compose.

An example here: https://github.com/digitalis-io/ccc